# TypeScript: compiler ignores alternative function signature

Tags: typescript

I'm using `lodash` with TypeScript 1.8. At one point in the code I want to reduce from an array like this:

```
export interface IPackage {
    [...]
    dependencies?: IPackageReference[];
    [...]
}

[...]

// pkg implements IPackageReference
lodash.reduce<IPackageReference, boolean>(pkg.dependencies, function(ref: IPackageReference, state: boolean) {
  return true;
}, true);
```

However, the compiler exits with a type mismatch:

```
package.ts(43,39): error TS2345: Argument of type 'IPackageReference[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Dictionary<IPackageReference>'.
  Index signature is missing in type 'IPackageReference[]'.
```

The typings I use support Arrays as the first argument however:

```
    /**
    * @see _.reduce
    **/
    reduce<T, TResult>(
        collection: Array<T>,
        callback: MemoIterator<T, TResult>,
        thisArg?: any): TResult;

    /**
    * @see _.reduce
    **/
    reduce<T, TResult>(
        collection: List<T>,
        callback: MemoIterator<T, TResult>,
        thisArg?: any): TResult;

    /**
    * @see _.reduce
    **/
    reduce<T, TResult>(
        collection: Dictionary<T>,
        callback: MemoIterator<T, TResult>,
        thisArg?: any): TResult;
```

How do I get TSC to recognize my parameter as Array?

Comment: You say `// pkg implements IPackageReference`, is that accurate? Should it not be imlpementing `IPackage`?

Comment: @Paarth ~~It is indeed the other interface.~~ Nah I was wrong and misremembered, both interfaces have `name` and `dependencies` - IPackageReference is an unresolved IPackage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the paramemters of the reduce callback switched out, just like @Paarth mentioned. However, I was a little mislead since the error showed up on the first argument. This is due to how TypeScript handles multiple function signatures. If any fail to match, the error checking is done against the *last defined* signature, not the closest matching.

GH Issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8693

Answer (score 1):

You have your reducer function parameters inverted based on [the documentation](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce). Try switching their order.

```
// pkg implements IPackageReference
lodash.reduce<IPackageReference, boolean>(pkg.dependencies, function(state: boolean, ref: IPackageReference) {
  return true;
}, true);
```

Sometimes things like this can have downstream effects where objects happen to be interpret-able as the wrong type and so the compiler proceeds.